# Will use of IOKit in my iOS app get my app rejected?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval, iokit

devs, as mentioned by [Erica](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/04/iphone-dev-iokit---the-missing.html) IOKit is a semi private framework; does anybody has any experience in using it in an app-store app?
I want to use it to get IMEI and ICCID number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call any non-documented Apple framework your app will be rejected. So it's very unlikely people have experience of using this framework in an app-store friendly app.

This process is *entirely automatic*, and happens immediately after you submit the binary. It's run through a number of checks to make sure you're not referencing or calling anything untoward.

Comment: @jonathan, @lxt thanks for the info, but as per Erica it is a semi private framework. I required IOKit to get the SIM related info; I need it to secure the app for a service provider.

Comment: There are other ways of securing apps for service providers...I know because I work on them. A 'semi private' framework is as the name suggests: not public. IOKit isn't permitted on app store apps because it allows developers to fundamentally alter device behaviour (device brightness, etc etc). Apple won't care about your needs, and the fact is there are lots of carrier unique apps on the store that manage perfectly well without IMEI. Unfortunately because Apple automatically analyse your code as it goes in to review there is no way around this.

Comment: If possible, can you give any hint towards the ways? or may be a link to gather more info?

Comment: They range from the fairly straightforward (you can use `CoreTelephony` to discover things like operator ID, name, etc) to somewhat more complex (service providers can obtain information such as IMEI over 3G connections, so you can setup nil-rate services that return IMEI and IMSI upon request - this does, however, require the service provider to implement such a service).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. IOKit is not a public framework on iOS.