# how to get IMSI number programmatically in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-number, imei

I am trying to get the IMSI number in iPhone by programming. Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: have you seen this? I havent tried it yet but people says you can get the IMEI throug this https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension

Comment: Yes but not showing anything in device, can you try it pls

Comment: maybe this [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone) help you

Comment: @Scar i tried it before but not successful:(

Answer (score 2):

Surprised this question still doesn't have an answer. There is no way to get IMSI on iOS.  Apple does not allow that due to security reasons.

And IMSI is different than IMEI. IMSI is an identifier to SIM card and IMEI is an identifier to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

For Your Information.. you can obtain IMEI using private frameworks -[See this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone) but may be  your app will be rejected from app store then.

If you want to obtain some device identifier to use in your application you must use uniqueIdentifier property defined in UIDevice class - it is there for exactly that purpose.

```
NSString* uniqueID = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
```

A unique device identifier is a hash value composed from various hardware identifiers such as the device’s serial number. It is guaranteed to be unique for every device but cannot publically be tied to a user account. You can use it, for example, to store high scores for a game in a central server or to control access to registered products. The unique device identifier is sometimes referred to by its abbreviation UDID.

Comment: Thanks but i have tried it before and getting a error in message.framework dont worry apple will approve it.

Comment: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m you are using this one right..?

Comment: If you call any non-documented Apple framework your app will be rejected.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869488/will-use-of-iokit-in-my-ios-app-get-my-app-rejected

Comment: The IMEI and IMSI are not the same thing.